# Sending changing Data from View to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I have a Activity and its Layout contains a CustomView in which I'm able to draw and I also got a Fragment in which I'll make a statistic about the used colors, stroke widths and one other variable. So I have to send the information to the Fragment.

How can I do that?

My first idea would be to make lists with the colors, strokes..., then adding every drawing to the color list it is made of, then getting the size of the list and at last sending it to the fragment.

Or I could make a variable and every time a color, stroke width and variable is added, the specific variable would increase, but here's the same problem that I don't know how to send the value to the Fragment.

The second problem is that this variable is changing, so if you made one small line in red and you go to the statisitc it should say 1 small red line. If you make another one, then it should say 2 small red lines, how can I receive the latest value of these values?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Interface to communicate between View and Fragment. Read more about Java interfaces [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)

```
public class drawView extends View {
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

    //
    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        public void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    public void setOnColorChangedListener(OnColorChangedListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
        //Call this method to implement this interface in your Fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        if(mListener != null){
            mListener.colorChanged(somecolor);
        }
    }
}

public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnColorChangedListener {
    public void onCreate(){
        drawView v = new drawView();
        v.setOnColorChangedListener(this);
    }
    //If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile. 
    public void colorChanged(int color){
        //Do your stuff with your color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use the Observer/Observable pattern. In this case, your CustomView is the Observable while your Fragment is the Observer. Create a Observer (or Listener interface) with an appropriate name, change the Fragment to implement this interface, and add a method to the CustomView to register the Fragment as a Listener. Now all you need to do is call the `onXxx()` method from your Listener interface in order to notify the Fragment that a line was drawn. The Fragment is then responsible for calculating the statistics you need.

Comment: I'm currently searching for some tutorials or good examples which are explaining the use and implementing of Observer and the pattern. Do you know something or do you want to explain it with a bit more depth. Regards